# elliptic PDE $\mathbf{u_{xx}+x^2u_{yy}=0}$ $\mathbf{u_{xx}}$ calculation using alternative coordinates $\xi$ and $\eta$.

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I am analysing an elliptic PDE $\mathbf{u_{xx}+x^2u_{yy}=0}$ and I don't understand how the below transitions  has been made. What rules have been used to get (2) and (3)

$\\(1) \ \ \ \xi = \frac{1}{2} x^2, \ \eta =y \\
(2) \ \ \ \frac{\partial }{\partial x} =x \frac{\partial }{\partial \xi}; \ \ \  \frac{\partial }{\partial y} = \frac{\partial }{\partial \eta} \\
(3) \ \ \ u_{xx} = u_{\xi} + x \frac{\partial }{\partial \xi} u_{\xi} = u_{\xi} + x^2 u_{\xi \xi}$

Answer (score 2):

By a coordinate transformation we mean that the same function can be described in two ways $u(x, y)$ and $u(\xi, \eta)$. We begin with $du = u_\xi d\xi + u_\eta d\eta$. Therefore,
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = u_\xi \frac{\partial\xi}{\partial x} + u_\eta\frac{\partial\eta}{\partial x} = xu_\xi + 0 = xu_\xi,
\end{equation}
We would like to differentiate this expression once more with respect to $x$. Since $u_\xi$ is also a function of $\xi$ and $\eta$, $du_\xi = u_{\xi\xi}d\xi + u_{\xi\eta}d\eta$ and hence,
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u_\xi}{\partial x} = u_{\xi\xi}x + 0
\end{equation}
Finally, since
\begin{equation}
u_{xx} = u_\xi + x\frac{\partial u_\xi}{\partial x} 
\end{equation}
we get $u_{xx} = u_\xi + x^2u_{\xi\xi}$.

Comment: ok, this part is clear, I got the following canonical form $u_{\xi \xi}+u_{\eta \eta}+ \frac{1}{2 \xi} u_{\xi} =0$, I am still struggling with the derivation of the general solution. Should  $u_{\eta \eta}$ be integrated twice with respect to $\xi$ ? what should it give?

Comment: The next steps depend on your boundary conditions. Check if they permit separation of variables.

Comment: There are no boundary conditions given to this problem. Does it mean that the general solution cannot be derived?

Comment: Can you describe the problem in this (or a separate) question? I would still recommend you to try 'separation of variables'.

Comment: I created a new question to the problem here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1602700/elliptic-pde-mathbfu-xxx2u-yy-0-general-solution