# elliptic PDE $\mathbf{u_{xx}+x^2u_{yy}=0}$ - general solution

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I got the canonical form of the the equation but I am not sure how the general solution should be derived in this case. Should all components be integrated twice w.r.t $\xi$ ? how about $u_{\eta \eta}$ ? what should it give?

canonical form 
$\mathbf{u_{\xi \xi}+u_{\eta \eta}+ \frac{1}{2 \xi} u_{\xi} =0}$

where 
 
$\xi=\frac{1}{2}x^2$

$\eta=y$